# Program that finds the biggest space between two appears of the entered character

Tags: c, character

So I made a program and it doesn't work right, and I wanted to see if anyone can help me. Maybe even the idea is not right, I'm not sure.
It should find the biggest space between two appears of the provided character, and print it, or if that character doesn't appear at least 2 times, print 0.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
main()

{

int i=0,k=0,max,a[50],j;
char n,c;

printf("Insert the character:\n");

scanf("%c",&n);

while ((c=getchar()) != EOF)
{
 if (c==n)
        {
         c=getchar();
         while (c != n)
                 {
                  k++;
                  c=getchar();
                 }
         a[i]=k;
         k=0;
         i++;
        }
}



max=a[0];

for (j=1; j<i; j++)
        if (a[j]>max) max=a[j];



if (max>=2) printf("%d\n",max);

else printf("0\n");

}
```

Comment: Suggestion: `main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n);` to scan a character? I strongly suggest reading the basics before you code.

Comment: I did some experimenting with the code and forgot to change the scanned type back to char, aswell as n,c variables. Thanks for pointing that out, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize `max` and `a[0]`.
2. Check for `EOF` in inner while loop.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
       int i=0,k=0,max,a[50],j;
       char n,c;
       a[0] = 0;                                     // Initialize a[0]
       max  = 0;                                     // Initialize max
       printf("Insert the character:\n");
       scanf("%c",&n);
       int end_reached = 0;
       while ((c=getchar()) != EOF)
       {
           if (c==n)
           {
               c=getchar();
               while (c != n)
               {
                   if(c == EOF) {                     // Check for EOF
                       end_reached = 1;
                       break;
                   }
                   k++;
                   c=getchar();
               }
               if(!end_reached) {                     // Store k in a only if end was not reached.
                   a[i]=k;
                   k=0;
                   i++;
               }
           }
       }
       max=a[0];
       for (j=1; j<i; j++)
           if (a[j]>max)
               max=a[j];
       if (max>=2) 
           printf("%d\n",max);
       else 
           printf("0\n");
   }
   ```